# How can I enter visual mode in Ubuntu?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I know how to and I have used it for a long time on Mac. But in Ubuntu whenever I press `Alt+V`, it goes to the system calendar instead of entering visual mode

I don't see it as a shortcut in Ubuntu too.

How can I make sure it enters the visual mode?

Comment: See the manual: `:h visual-use`

Answer (score 3):

3 types of `visual-mode`, While being in normal mode,

- press `v`, this will take you to `visual-mode`
- press `V` ( capital V ), this will take you to `visual-line` mode where you can visually select whole lines in a go.
- press `Ctrl-v`, this will take you to `visual-block` mode in which you can visually select blocks of text. If vim is compiled with the clipboard option, use `Ctrl-q` instead (`:help ctrl-v-alternative`).

Try each of them, you'll see the difference